# C++ CreateWindowEx() fails to create window

Tags: winapi

I've starting watching the handmade hero videos and I'm trying to make a win32 window but the CreateWindowEx() function keeps failing.

I checked the error code and I get 1407.

Code is below.

Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(
    HWND hwnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    LRESULT result;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("The window is now active");

            break;
        }

    case WM_SIZE:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("The window is now being resized");

            break;
        }

    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("The window has been created");

            break;
        }

    default:
        {
            result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
};

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
    )
{
    WNDCLASS GameWindow;

    GameWindow.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    GameWindow.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    GameWindow.hInstance = hInstance;
//      HICON     hIcon;
    GameWindow.lpszClassName = "HandmadeHeroWindowClass";

    RegisterClass(&GameWindow);

    if (HWND GameWindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        GameWindow.lpszClassName,
        "Handmade Hero",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0,
        0,
        hInstance,
        0
        ))
    {

        for (;;)
        {
            MSG message;
            BOOL messageResult = GetMessage(&message, GameWindowHandle, 0, 0);
            if (messageResult != 0)
            {
                DispatchMessage(&message);
            }
            else if (messageResult == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // ERROR
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("Couldn't create window");
    }

    DWORD error = GetLastError();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: 1407 == `ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS`

Comment: See if your register class succeeds. I am guessing it doesnt.

Comment: I agree with IMJ. `RegisterClass()` is likely failing, because many of the `WNDCLASS` fields are not being initialized. Always zero-initialize API structs, and always check error codes on API function calls.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much remy, I initialized all the fields to zero then changed the fields that I want and now it works. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Remy Lebeau for the answer, the problem was that my WNDCLASS had uninitialized values for all fields except those I changed, this caused the RegisterClass() to fail and consequently the CreateWindowEx() to fail.

I changed WNDCLASS declaration to this:

```
WNDCLASS GameWindow = {0};
```

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your window procedure returns an uninitialized variable in every path except for `default:`, this is undefined behavior and failure of window creation is entirely possible.

For `WM_CREATE`, the documentation says:

> If an application processes this message, it should return zero to continue creation of the window.

---

As Michael noted in the comments, `RegisterClass` is failing.  Same category of mistake, you're passing a `WNDCLASS` structure leaving most members uninitialized.

Comment: @Remy: The documentation doesn't actually say what happens for all non-zero values.  Just zero and -1.  Either way, returning an uninitialized value is UB.

Comment: I removed my switch and had it so that it returns DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam), still dont work.